# regex to extract sentence to the left of a word but not include words with dashes as whole words

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery, re2

I am trying to extract everything to the left of pin_delim.
This works fine for id 1,2,3,6 but fails for 5. id 4 is expected to return no results.
I can figure out how to stop pin_delim spliting on a dash -?

Any ideas on how to fix this and why is - being treated like a space?

I always want the last pin_delim string to the left.

**The university of de pere,delaware,de,usa**

RETURN 'The university of de pere,delaware,'
NOT 'The university of '

**saint-vincent-de-paul,delaware,de,usa**

RETURN 'saint-vincent-de-paul,delaware,de'
NOT 'saint-vincent-'

I have tried the following

```
 WITH t2 AS (
    WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT 1 id,'middleDEword French,de, Polynesia.' pin_senetence,'de' pin_delimiter,'middleDEword French,' expected
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 id, 'Saint-Vincent-de-Paul,de,usa','de','Saint-Vincent-de-Paul,'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 id,'HopiDEtal-de Saint Vincent de Paul,de,usa','de','HopiDEtal-de Saint Vincent de Paul,'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 id,'middleDEword French, Polynesia.' pin_snetence,'de','middleDEword French, Polynesia.'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 id,'Saint-Vincent-de-Paul,usa','de','Saint-Vincent-de-Paul,usa'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 id,'HopiDEtal-de Saint DE Vincent de Paul,usa','de','HopiDEtal-de Saint DE Vincent ')
SELECT id,
    pin_senetence,
    pin_delimiter,
    expected,
    LENGTH(pin_delimiter) substr_sec_param,
    LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT(pin_senetence, CONCAT( r'(?i)\b',  r'^(.*)', pin_delimiter,  r'\b.*'))) AS pos
    FROM t1
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(pin_senetence, CONCAT( r'(?i)\b',  r'^(.*)', pin_delimiter,  r'\b.*')))
    SELECT id,
    pin_senetence,
    SUBSTR(pin_senetence, pos + 1, substr_sec_param)          substr_val,
    SUBSTR(pin_senetence, 1, pos) actual,
    expected,
    IF(SUBSTR(pin_senetence, 1, pos) = expected, TRUE, FALSE) is_correct,
    pos,
    substr_sec_param
    FROM t2;


|id |pin_senetence                            |substr_val|actual                             |expected                           |is_correct|pos|substr_sec_param|
|---|-----------------------------------------|----------|-----------------------------------|-----------------------------------|----------|---|----------------|
|1  |middleDEword French,de, Polynesia.       |de        |middleDEword French,               |middleDEword French,               |TRUE      |20 |2               |
|2  |Saint-Vincent-de-Paul,de,usa             |de        |Saint-Vincent-de-Paul,             |Saint-Vincent-de-Paul,             |TRUE      |22 |2               |
|3  |HopiDEtal-de Saint Vincent de Paul,de,usa|de        |HopiDEtal-de Saint Vincent de Paul,|HopiDEtal-de Saint Vincent de Paul,|TRUE      |35 |2               |
|5  |Saint-Vincent-de-Paul,usa                |de        |Saint-Vincent-                     |Saint-Vincent-de-Paul,usa          |FALSE     |14 |2               |
|6  |HopiDEtal-de Saint DE Vincent de Paul,usa|de        |HopiDEtal-de Saint DE Vincent      |HopiDEtal-de Saint DE Vincent      |TRUE      |30 |2               |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to reverse the both strings, the text and the token `pin_delimiter`. In the regular expression we can search for the first occurance of the token "ed" (reversed "de") and take everyting after this. Reversing this result is the beginning of the string until the last occurance of the token.

For excluding `-` as token separator, please exclude these in `[^\w\-]`.

```sql
    WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT 1 id,'middleDEword French,de, Polynesia.' pin_senetence,'de' pin_delimiter,'middleDEword French,' expected
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 id, 'Saint-Vincent-de-Paul,de,usa','de','Saint-Vincent-de-Paul,'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 id,'HopiDEtal-de Saint Vincent de Paul,de,usa','de','HopiDEtal-de Saint Vincent de Paul,'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 id,'middleDEword French, Polynesia.' pin_snetence,'de','middleDEword French, Polynesia.'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 id,'Saint-Vincent-de-Paul,usa','de','Saint-Vincent-de-Paul,usa'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 id,'HopiDEtal-de Saint DE Vincent de Paul,usa','de','HopiDEtal-de Saint DE Vincent ')
SELECT *,
#substring(pin_senetence,1,length(pin_senetence)-length(text_ending)+2) as extracted,
substring(text_max,1,length(text_max)-length(pin_delimiter)-1) as text_extracted,
substring(text_max,1,length(text_max)-length(pin_delimiter)-1)=expected
from(
Select *,
#REGEXP_EXTRACT(concat(pin_senetence," "),CONCAT(r"([^\w\-]",pin_delimiter,r"[^\w\-].*)")) as text_ending,
reverse(REGEXP_EXTRACT(reverse(concat(pin_senetence," ")),CONCAT(r"(?i)([^\w\-]",reverse(pin_delimiter),r"[^\w\-].*)"))) as text_max
from t1
)
```

Comment: This is the part I was missing. 
`code`
reverse(REGEXP_EXTRACT(reverse(concat(pin_senetence," ")),CONCAT(r"(?i)([^\w\-]",reverse(pin_delimiter),r"[^\w\-].*)")))
`code`

good idea using reverse